# I have this error in my code, I'm trying to create a login page with firebase, email_authentication

Tags: flutter

Error:

> cannot find symbol
>
> void reportException(Result result, @Nullable Exception exception) {
>                                                 ^
>   symbol:   class Nullable
>   location: class FirebaseAuthPlugin
>   Execution failed for task ':firebase_auth:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>   Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
>   The Gradle failure may have been because of AndroidX incompatibilities in this Flutter app.

Answer (score 0):

Your error occured due this AndroidX incompatibilities

in gradle.properties add this

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```